# BFR: will there be no more gimballing of the first stage?

Tags: spacex, its

Is there any indication throttling would be used instead?

The underbelly of the BFR v2017 has not been shown in the IAC presentation, we only know it has 31 engines for a 9 meter diameter.

For comparison, we know the BFR v2016 had planned for gimballing, with 8 of them used for the landing part: 
[image: 42 engines, BFR v2016]

Comment: I have no idea why this was so heavily downvoted without any helpful comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gimballing has significantly quicker response than throttling so most probably no, differential throttling won't replace gimballed engines.

We just did not get to see the "business end" of the first stage because there was nothing "new" compared to last year. Just a different number of engines.

Comment: thanks, although all the 31 engine will need gimballing capacity then, instead of 8? Since the engines cones will be tighter together even more.

Comment: We probably just do not know. I do not recall any shot from the presentation where it could be seen.